# form becomes undefined within subscribe (template driven form)

Tags: angular

I have a method called onSubmit. It calls a restful API. I tried to console.log(form) with in the subscribe of the called API. But it shows undefined.

```
  onSubmit = (form: NgForm) => {
     console.log(form); // form
     console.log(this.dd)
     const newUser = {email: form.value.email, password: form.value.password};
    
     console.log(newUser);
     this.loading = true;
     this.authService.signUp(form.value.email, form.value.password)
      .subscribe((data: { message: string, token: string }) => {
         console.log(data);
         console.log(form) // undefined
     
         this.loading = false;

    }, (error) => {
      console.log(error.error);
      // window.alert(error.message)
      this.error = error.error;
      this.loading = false;


    });
 }
```

I don't understand why form becomes undefined within subscribe.

Edit: Here is the html template and the signup method

```
    <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" *ngIf="!loading">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email"> Email</label>
    <input type="email" id="email" class="form-control" ngModel name="email" required email #ff>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="password"> Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" class="form-control" ngModel name="password" required minlength="6">
  </div>
  <div>
  <button [disabled]="!f.valid" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">{{logMode?"Login":"Sign up"}}</button> |
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"   (click)="onSwitchMode()">Switch to {{logMode? "Sign up" : "Login"}}</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

I also tried to get the refElement from the form, and its value also becomes undefined within the subscribe. However, I could get the refElement if the elment is not in the form. For example, I added a new input element outside the form, and I could get the refElement inside the subscribe. So, I am wondering if template driven form is not accessible in this sutation.

```
  signUp = (email1: string, password1: string) => {
    const newUser = {email: email1, password: password1};
    return this.httpClient.post('http://localhost:5000/realUsers/add',
      newUser);   }
```

Comment: You need to check the [official documentation](https://angular.io/guide/forms#submit-the-form-with-ngsubmit) about `template driven forms`. You can reach the form value from your model.

Comment: Could you please share your template file for more clarification?

Comment: Just added. Thanks for the advice. I am new to angular. I suspect that template form is not accessible within restful API subscribe.

Comment: @die please check first whether you are receiving values or not? try to use the `console.log(f.value)` onSubmit before calling API Service.

Comment: @die, as you have defined form `ngForm` then use this `[(ngModel)]="ngForm.email"`

Comment: console.log(f.value) onSubmit before calling API Service does print its value. .